# VHDL syntax for arrays of clocks (accepted by synthesis but not Active-HDL simulator)

Tags: vhdl

I've a problem with some VHDL syntax in some old code that I want to reuse. It is accepted by the synthesis tool (Synplify) but the simulator (Aldec Active-HDL 8.3) gives the following error. (Note: This construction was accepted by a previous version of this simulator).

#Error: COMP96_0228: buffered_data.vhdl : (19, 28): The actual must be denoted by a static signal name, if the actual is associated with a signal parameter of any mode.

I get that the error doesn't like the (i) in the signal clk(i) but I don't want to unroll the loop to (0),(1),etc because it's used in several different configurations for different port sizes and I'm sure there must be a way to describe this.

My solution so far is to encapsulate one instance in it's own entity/arch hierarchy and use a "generate" to instantiate once for each port but I don't like it.  Any better ideas?

Very simplified example showing exactly my issue. (The intent is to ensure that data is first clocked into the FPGA using its own associated clock before anything else)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity input_buffer is
     port(
         clk : in std_logic_vector;
         data_in : in std_logic_vector;
         data_out : out std_logic_vector
         );
end input_buffer;

architecture rtl of input_buffer is
    constant c_NumOfPorts : integer := 3;
begin

    p_process: process(clk)
    begin
        for i in 0 to c_NumOfPorts-1 loop
            if rising_edge(clk(i)) then -- error here
                data_out(i) <= data_in(i);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;

end rtl;
```

Comment: Just out a curiosity, what language option do you have enabled in Active-HDL and what version of synplify are you using? The language support differences between these two tools has often caused me some heartburn as well.

Comment: Currently using Synplify Pro D-2009.12A but earlier versions behave the same in this regard.

Both of the following Active-HDL 8.3 commands show this:

acom -O3 -work work -2002  $dsn/src/buffered_data.vhdl
acom -O3 -work work -2008  $dsn/src/buffered_data.vhdl

I haven't found any other combination that accepted this syntax (which may not be valid).

7.3 didn't support -2008, but then it didn't have a problem with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the loop inside the process into a generate statement outside the process, it works fine in ModelSim (I don't have Aldec available), and IMHO seems cleaner than a single process with a bunch of clocks.  I would also typically use a generic to define the port widths, rather than pulling them in as a constant inside the architecture, but I figure you've got some reason for doing it that way:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity input_buffer is
     port(
         clk : in std_logic_vector;
         data_in : in std_logic_vector;
         data_out : out std_logic_vector
         );
end input_buffer;

architecture rtl of input_buffer is
    constant c_NumOfPorts : integer := 3;
begin

    gen : for i in 0 to c_NumOfPorts-1 generate
    begin
        p_process: process(clk(i))
        begin
            if rising_edge(clk(i)) then -- error here
                data_out(i) <= data_in(i);
            end if;
        end process;
    end generate;

end rtl;
```

Comment: Thanks. Could have sworn I'd already tried to nest the process per-clock in a generate like you've done, but that's definitely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I get the same with Modelsim:

```
Model Technology ModelSim PE vcom 10.0a Compiler 2011.02 Feb 20 2011
-- Loading package STANDARD
-- Loading package TEXTIO
-- Loading package std_logic_1164
-- Compiling entity input_buffer
-- Compiling architecture rtl of input_buffer
** Error: clk.vhd(19): (vcom-1450) Actual (indexed name) for formal "s" is not a static signal name.
** Error: clk.vhd(25): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

As an aside - is there a reason for your use of the `constant` and not just doing this?

```
    for i in clk'range loop
```

But no actual answer has occurred to me yet, sorry!

Comment: It's a simplified example. In the original code, the constant is coming in from a package and not every element of clk may be used.  The question is more related to how better to write rising_edge(clk(i)) or rearrange the code in a way that doesn't require declaring individual signals for each element of clk.  I'm actually pleased that this is also an error with ModelSim as it means Active-HDL is probably correct and the code is probably wrong. But correct in this circumstance is still defined as what the synthesis tool accepts :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now!  (And kicking myself for not seeing the "generate outside the process" solution, as I used it myself just a couple of weeks ago!)